# Pointer to NSUInteger

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Can I convert a pointer to NSUInteger and reliably compare values to test for object equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be testing that the pointers refer to the same object. Or in other words, that the pointers are equal.

But you can do that without casting them to NSUInteger.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just compare pointers directly? This code:

```
NSString *foo = @"Hello,";
NSString *bar = @"World!";

if (foo == bar) {
    // Do something.
}
```

is testing for pointer equality, no conversion needed.

Comment: I am thinking of storing the uints in NSSets, for faster membership tests (whether or not they are really faster, I don't know).

Comment: You can’t store primitive types (int, char, etc.) in an NSSet, but even if you could, this seems like premature optimization to me. Are you having a problem with the speed of NSSets in general?

Comment: Oops, sorry I meant to say NSIndexSets.

Comment: technically, you can store builtin types in an NSSet by creating a CFSetRef and specifying an appropriate CFAllocator to use.